# How to avoid the repetition of a noun in German?

Tags: noun, pronoun

I don't see myself good at referring a noun secondly in other part of sentences that its subject is the same thing. That's why for simplicity I go for "es". But I think "es" is used only when the article of a noun "das" is. Could you please explain the rules on following sample if that works?

> In diesem Satz ist eine Präposition falsch gewählt und deshalb verursacht (sie/die) die Ausdrucksfehler?

I know using here "sie/die" may be superfluous,but say that I have to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don’t necessarily need to repeat the noun:

> *In diesem Satz ist eine Präposition falsch gewählt und verursacht deshalb (die/einen) Ausdrucksfehler*

Would be perfect German. I would prefer to leave out the *die/einen*.

Or, in two sentences:

> *In diesem Satz ist eine Präposition falsch gewählt. Dies verursacht Ausdrucksfehler*

In this case, *dies* serves the purpose of the article. Here as well, I would prefer to leave out I put in brackets.

Comment: The two sentence example has a different meaning though. In the first example, the preposition is the cause of the errors, while in the second, the choosing of the wrong preposition is causing them.

Comment: Should it be "deshalb (*den*/einen) Ausdrucksfehler"?

Comment: @Iris It could be multiple mistakes, though the singular indefinite article seems best fitting.

Comment: Die Preapostion.=> dies or diese verursacht...?

Comment: @Iris,Ausdrucksfehler is multiple.

Comment: @user1474062, no, it can be one or multiple.

Comment: the second example is not the same. "Dies" relates to the fact mentioned in the first sentenance, not to the noun itself

Answer (score 2):

Using *sie* to rereference the noun is one correct way to go. As Tofro pointed out, some people may find other varieties more beautiful.

> In diesem Satz ist eine Präposition falsch gewählt und deshalb verursacht sie die Ausdrucksfehler.

Comment: I've noticed two different word order between yours and Tofro's that was: "[...]und deshalb verursacht [...]", "[...]und verursacht deshalb[...]".Now I wonder what is difference between the two :/

Comment: @Dragut The key difference is the missing *sie* in Tofro’s answer. I made two main clauses connected with *und*; the second clause must have something between conjunction and verb so that the verb is second. Tofro’s version is more of a single main clause in which the subject is not repeated in the second half and therefore *verursacht* must be following *und* immediately.